# Java regex matching either a word or a punctuation sign

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that would match  either a word, or any punctuation sign, except for hyphen (-). In other words, I'd like the regex to treat hyphen as a part of a word. The solutions I came up with didn't work out for me:

```
 [^[(?![-])\p{Punct}]\s]+|(?![-])\p{Punct}
 [^[\p{Punct}&&[^-]]\s]+ |[\p{Punct}&&[^-]]
```

(The first part of alternation is supposed to match words (including words with hyphen), and the second is to match any punctuation sign but for hyphen).

Could someone, please, enlighten me on this subject? I'm completely new to regular expressions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you say your 1st attempt doesn't work? Seems to be working for me. Add some context maybe?

Comment: `[\\p{Punct}&&[^-]]` works fine for me. Anyway problem with your `[^[(?![-])\p{Punct}]\\s]+|(?![-])\\p{Punct}` regex is that you forgot that `[...]` is character class, so each character (except `^` at start, `-`, `[` and `]` (if there is `[` unescaped and unclosed before it) is treated as literal so `[(?![-])]` is matching `(` `?` `!` `-` and `)`. Consider adding example of input and expected output with little explanation why such output is expected.

Comment: @upvoter I am just curious, did you upvote this question to balance its -1 (fully deserved because question is unclear/unanswarable in this form) OR would you upvote it anyway?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I agree that the question might look a bit unclear, so I'll change the formulation.

Comment: Java ignores the caret at the start of a character class when the caret is immediately followed by a nested class.

Comment: @Andie Thanks, that's really the problem with my regex. I'll post the solution as soon as I come up with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution that perfectly satisfies my needs. Hope this helps someone, who might be experiencing similar problem.

```
[[^\p{Punct}\s]-]+|[\p{Punct}]
```